# Media Player Forward & Backwarding issues

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my code The forward & back ward (these are button click events) are working after the file played(stopped).My aim is to fwd/bckwd while plying the file.

Here is my code

```
       forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position                
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
            if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
            }else{
                // forward to end position
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }

        }
    });
        backward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position                
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
            if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
            }else{
                // backward to starting position
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
            // update timer progress again
            updateProgressBar();
        }
    });




private void playAudio(String path) 
{
    Log.i("play","riyasssss");
    playing_started=true;
    // Play song
            try {
                mp.reset();
                mp.setDataSource(path);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();

                // Changing Button Image to pause image
                play.setText("Puase");

                // set Progress bar values
                sb.setProgress(0);
                sb.setMax(100);

                // Updating progress bar
                updateProgressBar();            
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}




/**
 * Update timer on seekbar
 * */
public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);        
}   

/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
           long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

           // Displaying Total Duration time
           total_time.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
          // Displaying time completed playing
           current_time.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

           // Updating progress bar
           int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
           //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
           sb.setProgress(progress);



              if(current_time.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(total_time.getText().toString()))
               {
                   //playingStarted=0;
                   play.setText("Play");

               }
               if(totalDuration<currentDuration)
               {
                   mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000000);
                    System.out.println("time task waited !!!!!!!!!!!");

               }



           // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
       }
    };

    `
```

Please Give me a soln..Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
     {
          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) 
            {
                 if(mp != null)
                 {
                     mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                     mp.stop();
                    // mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                     mp.release();`enter code here`
                 }
                 finish();
                 return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
     }
```